# Monitor a websocket (Minecraft) connection (not in the browser)

Tags: network-monitor, gaming, websocket

I'm trying to reverse engineer Minecraft BE's web socket API, which is primarily made for education. Minecraft is the client, and I can use any IP address as a server, such as `127.0.0.1`.

Is there any software that I can use to monitor the websocket client's messages send to the server?

Answer (score 1):

If the connection is not encrypted (TLS/SSL) you can probably sniff it with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or any other network sniffer.